# How to fix message to appear in new line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, newline, chatbot

I have created a chatbot program written in javascript. Whenever user hits enter, the response is coming in same line instead of going to new line. As advised I have added the code for loadresponse() too. Here is the snippet of the code:

```
// function to display success response in conversation div
function loadResponse(lexResponse) {

    var conversationDiv = document.getElementById('conversation');
    var responsePara = document.createElement("P");
    responsePara.className = 'lexResponse';
    if (lexResponse.message) {
        responsePara.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lexResponse.message));
        responsePara.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
```

The messages are not appearing in new line instead appearing on same line

Comment: Which is the part that displays the response? If it's the `loadResponse()` function, please show that code as well.

Comment: I have edited the code

Comment: Add `conversationDiv.appendChild(responsePara);` and make sure you don't have `.lexResponse {
  display: inline;
}` in your css

Comment: Does this line also refers to as new line: (responsePara.appendChild(document.createElement('br')); ?

Comment: Yes, check the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/herbowicz/u4Ldjg2f/4/

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue. I checked your example and its working over there but when I to my chatbot program, the messages are not displayed properly

Comment: I have added my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/smahajan/naod8vm2/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append the `<br />` to the `innerHTML` property.

```
responsePara.innerHTML = `${responsePara.innerHTML}<br />`;
```

Comment: The response is still coming on same line

Comment: do you want the <br /> before the response? `<br />${responsePara.innerHTML}<br />`;

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue with it